# .Net Code asp.net Lambda: duplicate AWS cloudwatch logs, one not formatted

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

This is happening with a .Net Core ASP.Net  Lambda application using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging and AWS.Logger.AspNetCore. After (re)deploying/publishing the lambda, the initial call (using Postman) 2 logs show up in CW. E.g.:

```
2019/02/10T01.29.56 - 7f017ed5-857d-41af-8a6d-624ddc2be024
2019/02/10/[$LATEST]24ab4b53f17d4be3a2507331e968bbf7
```

The first contains a dozen or so entries, both internal Microsoft MVC messages and my explicit Log calls. For example:

```
[2/10/19 1:29:58 AM] Debug: Incoming POST requests to /api/carrierprogram/LaunchSendOffer/57e30620-571b-4b68-a86b-2ef4cb53f1a8/28
[2/10/19 1:29:58 AM] Debug: ASP.NET  Core Request PathBase: /Stage, Path: /api/carrierprogram/LaunchSendOffer/57e30620-571b-4b68-a86b-2ef4cb53f1a8/28
```

The second log has slightly different content, and the messages are not formatted:

```
[40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: Controllers.CarrierProgramController[0]
LaunchSendOffer(0) for programId '57e30620-571b-4b68-a86b-2ef4cb53f1a8', offerId '28'
```

A second request posted to the Lambda returns successfully, but the same explicit log calls recorded on the first call do not show up at all in the first log.

Here's a snippet from Startup.cs that populates the DI services repository

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
    ...
        var awsConfig = Log.CompleteAwsConfiguration(Configuration.GetAWSLoggingConfigSection());
        var loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory()
            .AddAWSProvider(awsConfig,
                formatter: (logLevel, message, exception) => $"[{DateTime.UtcNow}] {logLevel}: {message}")
            .AddConsole()
            .AddDebug();
        services.AddSingleton(loggerFactory);
    ...

    }
```

And how the logger is referenced in a controller class

```
private static ILogger<CarrierProgramController> _log;

    public CarrierProgramController(..., ILogger<CarrierProgramController> logger)
    {
        _log = logger;
    }
```

and a sample call:

```
_log.LogInformation($"LaunchSendOffer(0) for programId '{programId}', offerId '{offerId}'");
```

I suspect this is due to how the application is coded (DI C#), but this is mostly a black box and it's hard to troubleshoot. My questions

Why at there 2 logs generated?
Why are the entries in the second log unformatted (no log level prefix)?
Why do subsequent calls to the Lambda not add to the log(s)?

Answer (score 3):

I replaced the reference to AWS.Logger.AspNetCore with Amazon.Lambda.Logging.AspNetCore. This post shed some light on the behavior: https://github.com/aws/aws-logging-dotnet/issues/52

After replacing the package, there were a few additional changes. I removed the section in the Configuration method in the 7 line snippet above. And in the Configure() method in Startup.cs:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
```

Added this line:

```
loggerFactory.AddLambdaLogger(Configuration.GetLambdaLoggerOptions());
```

All the other changes, e.g. constructors in the controller and service classes were the same. Meaning I didn't have to add the logger/factory back to the services collection for DI.

So to answer my 3 questions - they all seem related to the use of the incorrect package, and switching to Amazon.Lambda.Logging.AspNetCore returned to expected behavior.